# How to have all logs?

Tags: python, logging, sanic, uvicorn

I try to have a basic config for logs. I know I have a KeyError in the code with a KeyError but It doesn't show me this error in the log file.

(I use Sanic and Uvicorn)

api.py

```
uvicorn.run(
  app, # Sanic app
  host=config['sanic']['host'],
  port=config['sanic']['port'],
  log_level=logging.DEBUG,
  log_config=logging.basicConfig(
    filename='logs/logtest.log',
    filemode='w',
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
  )
)
```

logtest.log

```
2020-05-18 13:16:05,449 DEBUG Using selector: SelectSelector
2020-05-18 13:16:05,456 INFO Started server process [1736]
2020-05-18 13:16:05,456 INFO Waiting for application startup.
2020-05-18 13:16:05,457 INFO Application startup complete.
2020-05-18 13:16:05,457 INFO Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2020-05-18 13:16:08,939 INFO 127.0.0.1:65153 - "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 200
```

I want to see in the log file:

```
2020-05-18 13:16:08,939 INFO Traceback (most recent call last): File "<input>", line 1, in <module> KeyError: 'test'
```

Sorry i don't know if it's understandable but ...
Thanks to everyone who can help me !

EDIT:

```
def get_result() -> dict:
  my_dict = {}
  my_dict['test'] = "I know it's an ERROR but why it doesn't show in log !!"
  return my_dict

@app.route('/index', methods=['GET'])
def index(request):
  return get_result()
```

Comment: It's in your `app` code. Can you show app code?

Comment: Yes ! I edited it

Comment: Have you read the section on logging in the docs?

https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/logging.html

You want the sanic.error logger.

Answer (score 0):

The log config for uvicorn is only used for the logs of **uvicorn itself**.

To log your application you need to configure logging for your application separately.

Read [python logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) to understand how to do that. Once you configured your logging you can log your exception.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def get_result() -> dict:
  try:
    my_dict = {}
    my_dict['test'] = "I know it's an ERROR but why it doesn't show in log !!"
    return my_dict
  except Exception:
    logger.exception("Oops! Error occurred")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I already used Flask and if I remember I didn't need to do try, except. It's automatically catch the error without try except. Is it posssible to do the same ?